# What causes Android phone to disconnect with BLuetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am pairing an Android Application with a BlueTooth device. I observe that there are several events that cause the pairing to be "disconnected" (such as placing the phone in my pocket). Since the phone is within the range of the BlueTooth device shouldn't the pairing be "continuous". What causes the disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of information about your device and application, the only explanation that can be given is regarding the characteristics of bluetooth transmissions. Since they operate at ultra high frequencies (UHF - around 2400 Mhz) and have low power, the wave propagation distance is very limited.

Furthermore, like any other radio wave, they are easily disrupted by some obstacles or interference. For example, it is possible that the material from which your clothes are made is attenuating the bluetooth signal.